# How to pre-empt Guice's CreationException for optional components

Tags: guice

I have a class like:

```
class Foo {
    Foo(@Named("x") x) { ... }
}
```

`x` is bound from a `Properties` object:

```
Names.bindProperties(binder(), props);
```

But if `x` is not set, I want to skip binding `Foo`. One way to accomplish this is:

```
if (props.contains("x")) {
    bind(Foo.class);
}
```

But is there a better way?

```
if (namedPropsBound(Foo.class)) { // how to implement this method?
    bind(Foo.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Was: Annotating x with @Nullable should do the Trick. Of course, this only allows injection of missing X in Foo, it does not avoid injection of Foo.

Try this: 
You could use a TypeListener as described in http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomInjections. Whenever Guice tries to inject a Foo, you could block that depending on the state of your properties.

Comment: I'd still get a Foo instantiated though. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Interesting idea, but even if this could be made to work (constructor injection, Foo is actually registered with a Multibinder etc), it looks like this might end up being a lot uglier and no more generic than the one-line conditional statement I have now.

Comment: Granted ... with the TypeListener approach, you would not have to rely on requireExplicitBindings(), though.